# Overloading bracket assignment in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, nsobject

I am in the process of porting an Objective-C application to C++ and I decided to create a class similar to NSObject and NSDictionary. If you are unfamiliar with this system, an NSObject is an object which all objects inherit form in Obj-C and then there is a reference counting mechanism within it. When there are no more references, the object frees itself.

In my code, I would like to be able to do the following

```
CMDictionary["Key"] = Object;
```

Internally, this is stored as

```
Map<string, CMObject*> mDictionary
```

Whenever a new object is assigned into the object, the dictionary must then retain this object by calling its retain function as well as calling release on any object that this new object might have replaced. My problem stems from the fact that I cannot find anyway to run code and determine when the brackets are being used in an assignment as I would not want the retain function to be called when I wrote something like

```
CMDicionary["key"]->StringValue();
```

Would there by anyway to do this, or would I need to just use getter/setter functions to modify my dictionary

Comment: Don't overengineer this, and don't approach this with such a strict OOP mindset -- replace `NSObject` with `std::shared_ptr<>` and `NSDictionary` with `std::unordered_map<>`. The way you're trying to do it, it would be kludgey at best to properly track the `CMObject*`s that you must allocate and dellocate (as you seem to be discovering, apparent from your replies to the current answers).

Comment: I am porting to a cross platform system which distributes to a variety of different architectures (mobile and desktop). The C++ 11 standards are not yet available and will not be for some time.

Comment: Not sure what you're thinking of, but the C++11 standard has been published since 2011-04-11... Welcome to 2012? ;-]

Comment: They are not yet available for simultaneous cross compilation to Symbian, iOS, Android, Bada, PC, and OSX using the Marmalade platform. Hopefully that clears it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you typically do in this situation is to implement:

```
Object const& Map::operator[](string) const;
Object& Map::operator[](string);
```

Note that I wrote `Object&` instead of `Object`. You can at any rate instantiate a new Object and hand it out, relying on a proper `Object& Object::operator=(Object const&)` to be implemented, which will then perform the assignment, **after** your `Map::operator[]` function returns (don't worry, the compiler will optimise it away in most cases).

Comment: Sounds great! I didn't realize that this was legal in C++. I'll check it out and mark it was the answer if it works correctly.

Comment: I just thought of a problem... I could tell by what is passed if I am going to need to release an old object, but I see no way to retain any new object that is getting assigned using this method.

Comment: @David: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. Could you clarify?

Comment: So when I assign, I would use this pseudo code:  SetObject(key k, object o) {if(isSet(k) Objects[k]->release; InternalDictSet(k,o);o->retain;}

When using the brackets, I would know that my object was about to be overwritten with Object& Map::operator[](string); so I could release the old object if it was there for that key, but there would be no way to retain the new object that I can see.

Comment: I think this is something that belongs in the Object class. Your map should only concern itself, with allocating the first Object in that slot and afterwards only return a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

You should overload the `operator[]` to accept a string.

http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html

Comment: This does not fix the whole problem. Read the bottom of my post. How do you tell if you are using it to assign or to read? You don't want to double retain just because you read.

Comment: Oh I see the issue here. Sorry for giving an incomplete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing a new class similar to `shared_ptr<CMObject*>` and do the retain/release inside of that object.

Comment: Better yet, just use `shared_ptr<>` itself -- attempting to reinvent it will only end in pain.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am porting to a cross platform system which deploys to a variety of Arm and X86 type systems. The C++ 11 standards are not yet available for all these systems and so I am stuck doing it the old fashion way.

Comment: @David : The old fashioned way would be `boost::shared_ptr<>` and `boost::unordered_map<>` -- still no need to reinvent the wheel here. :-]

Comment: We've been looking into getting boost cross compiling to all these platforms with mixed results. I'm sure it will get there eventually, but hopefully sooner rather than later

Comment: @David : FWIW the two libraries I mentioned are header-only, no linking needed, and consequently no more cross-compiling needed than just cross-compiling your own application.

Comment: I was unaware of this. I'll have to donwnload this and give it a try. Thanks for the tip!